# Move div on top/bottom with left fixed navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, padding, fixed

For some reason, when I am in md to lg class screen size, the header blue div drops down [gives top padding]. Is there anyway to set it "fixed" at top? Second, is there a way to also set it under the top nav when the phone size shows up? aka col-sm and col-xs

```
<div class="col-lg-12" id="Div1" style="border-left:0px; background-color:Blue; top:0; height:100px;">
```

The jsfiddle version for some reason doesn't show the md to lg top padding issue but it does show up in Google Chrome.

https://jsfiddle.net/cwmc6zc2/

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your sample code and ran it locally. It doesn't drop down in any browser I try.

[But are you scaling your fonts?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPV0n.png)

Left hand side is IE 11 and right hand side is Chrome's "toggle device toolbar".
I also like to add "@media **only screen** ... in my media queries.

Comment: I added the Font awesome icons and added this meta tag     

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

I think that is why the fonts were scaling. but it still doesn't drop down.